# Reemplazar una imagen por otra PHP y MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo mi código para editar imágenes en mi base de datos, pero a la hora de reemplazar la imagen en la carpeta o la ruta dónde se guarda no las reemplaza, sino añade una nueva.

Dejo imagen a continuación:
[image: La imagen que está subrayada en amarillo es la que quiero reemplazar. Y la imagen que está subrayada con gris es la nueva imagen. Pero en vez de reemplazar la imagen vieja por la nueva solo la agrega y ya.]

La imagen que está subrayada en amarillo es la que quiero reemplazar. Y la imagen  que está subrayada con gris es la nueva imagen. Pero en vez de reemplazar la imagen vieja por la nueva solo la agrega y ya.

Éste es mi código:

```
<?php 
session_start();

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "trigoyponque2017");

$id             = $_GET['id'];
$titulo         = $_POST['titulo'];
$descripcion    = $_POST['descripcion'];

$foto1   = $_FILES["foto"]["name"];
$foto    = rand(0,9).rand(100,9999).rand(100,9999).".".$foto1;
$ruta    = $_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"];
$destino = "../productos/".$foto;
move_uploaded_file($ruta,$destino);

if($_FILES["foto"]["name"]){
    $editar   = "UPDATE producto SET titulo= '$titulo', descripcion = '$descripcion', foto = '$foto' WHERE id= '$id'";
    echo "<script> alert ('Producto actualizado correctamente.'); window.location='editar_producto1.php?id=$id' </script>";
}else{
    $editar   = "UPDATE producto SET titulo= '$titulo', descripcion = '$descripcion' WHERE id= '$id'";
    echo "<script> alert ('Producto actualizado correctamente.'); window.location='editar_producto1.php?id=$id' </script>";
}



$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$editar);

if(!$resultado){
    echo "<script> alert('Error.'); window.location='editar_producto1.php?id=$id'</script>";
}else{
    echo "<script> alert('Producto actualizado correctamente.'); window.location='editar_producto1.php?id=$id'></script>";
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

PD: Cabe aclarar que estoy guardando las fotos con números random como una especia de ID.

Imagen en Base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es borrar la imagen, para eso debes usar unlink("rutaimg");

Comment: Según por lo que veo en el unlink estas indicando la ubicación donde esta la imagen pero no le especificas el nombre que tiene que borrar, de esa manera solo la eliminas de la base de datos solamente

Answer (score 1):

Eso pasa por que en ningún momento estas cambiando la foto en la carpeta nueva, siempre la estas añadiendo, entonces debes primero seleccionar la foto actual, eliminarla y ahí si seguir con tu flujo normal, algo así:

```
$foto1   = $_FILES["foto"]["name"];
$foto    = rand(0,9).rand(100,9999).rand(100,9999).".".$foto1;
$ruta    = $_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"];
$destino = "../productos/".$foto;

$selecionar = "SELECT foto FROM producto WHERE id = '$id'";
$resultado_seleccionar = mysqli_query($conexion, $selecionar);

$foto_db = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_seleccionar);
$ruta_foto_db = "../productos/" . $foto_db['foto'];

if(file_exists($ruta_foto_db)){
    unlink($ruta_foto_db);
}

if (!file_exists($destino)) {
    move_uploaded_file($ruta,$destino);
}

if($_FILES["foto"]["name"]){
    $editar   = "UPDATE producto SET titulo= '$titulo', descripcion = '$descripcion', foto = '$foto' WHERE id= '$id'";
    echo "<script> alert ('Producto actualizado correctamente.'); window.location='editar_producto1.php?id=$id' </script>";
}else{
    $editar   = "UPDATE producto SET titulo= '$titulo', descripcion = '$descripcion' WHERE id= '$id'";
    echo "<script> alert ('Producto actualizado correctamente.'); window.location='editar_producto1.php?id=$id' </script>";
}
```

Comment: Hice lo que me recomendaste, pero ahora me aparece un error de permisos.                                                                                                                                              unlink(../productos/): Permission denied in C:\wamp64\www\panaderia\php\editar_producto2.php on line 48

Comment: ¿Estás haciendo un unlink de un directorio (unlink(../productos/))? ¿No se trataba de archivos individuales?

Comment: @JaviMollá `$ruta_foto_db` guarda la ruta de un archivo, no de un directorio `"../productos/" . $foto_db['foto'];` por lo que quedaría algo como `"../productos/mifoto.jpg";`

Comment: pero en el error pone solo la ruta del directorio